# JScrollPane - CrossBrowser Scrollbars - Inconsistent and Crashing

Tags: jquery, scroll, jscrollpane, smoothing

Using the JQuery plugin JScrollPane I have created a series of scrollable divs styled to look like those from the iPhone.

In theory it is all working but there are 3 fundamental problems.

- The plugin appears to be operating slowly and arbitrarily not scrolling certain content, tinning it up and breaking the scrollable panel. see example page http://www.golfbrowser.com/WebObjects/course-pack.html
- The scrolling is jerky and static, not smooth at all
- Also due to the nature of the site it could do with some elasticity. This is not a major priority though unlike the other two.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set options for animated scrol :

```
$('selector').jScrollPane({
    animateScroll : true,
    animateDuration : 1000,
    animateEase : 'swing'
});
```

More info about the plugin [here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html).